Java - 500 Internal Server Error: Given ID must not be null (SOLVED)
SOLVED- It turns out that it is best practice for the first character of JSON Properties, as well as the field in your Class to start with a lowercase letter, which was not the case for the null field.
I will make the corrections to original question
I am working with books and authors specifically for an API, where I am using Java Spring Boot and Spring JPA with hibernate with MySQL database.
My Book Class:
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    private String isbn; //Was formally set to 'ISBN'

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="books_orders",
            joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name="book_isbn"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
    )
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name="books_authors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_isbn"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    )
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();


    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.Isbn = isbn;
    }


    public Set<Author> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }

    public void setAuthors(Set<Author> authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }

My Author Class:
@Entity
public class Author {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="authors")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    private String name;
    private int birthyear;
    private String nationality;


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getBirthyear() {
        return birthyear;
    }

    public void setBirthyear(int birthyear) {
        this.birthyear = birthyear;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public Set<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }
}

JSON Payload for Book:
{
    "isbn": "ISBN1",
    "authors": [
        {"id": 47, "name": "Eichiro Oda", "birthyear": 1976, "nationality": "Japanese"}
    ],
    "title": "One piece",
    "publicationYear": 1999,
    "price": 100.00
}

The Controller method handling book creation:
    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createBook(@RequestBody Book book, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
        if (bRepo.existsById(book.getIsbn())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse("The book named " + book.getTitle() + " already exists."), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        bRepo.save(book);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/api/book/{ISBN}").buildAndExpand(book.getIsbn()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

When I am testing the POST endpoint with a Book Request Body to create a book I get this specific error:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-04-22T22:37:17.571+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given id must not be null\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335)\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)\n\tat jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy118.existsById(Unknown Source)\n\tat edu.leicester.co2103.part1s2.controller.BookRestController.createAuthor(BookRestController.java:83)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:925)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null\n\tat org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:172)\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.existsById(SimpleJpaRepository.java:342)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\n\t... 58 more\n",
    "message": "The given id must not be null",
    "path": "/books/"
}



When I debugged the controller method, I realized the primary key field for the book in the request body was null, and I figured that there may be a problem with setting string primary keys.

If the createAuthor method is supposed to persist an author, it should probably receive an author JSON payload. If it's supposed to persist a book, then maybe it should be called createBook and the JSON payload you're sending should include an ISBN property, which seems to be your missing id.

Hello sir/madam, thank you for your response. I am sorry about those silly typos, I've fixed them, but I still get the error when testing

Please don't edit your question to indicate your problem is solved. Instead, you can answer your own question.

@dan1st, Thank you for the correction, I am new here, I will put this in mind next time, thank you!

If you're using Spring's defaults, then you're implicitly using Jackson for JSON (de)serialization. Thus, you can take a look at the @JsonProperty for custom names (and maybe the rest of the annotations to better get accustomed to Jackson).
